# OpenSSL incompatibility with Windows API

Tags: php, winapi, curl, openssl, timestamp

I am trying to use a timestamp service in both php and windows.
My problem is that, what openssl outputs is not seem to be compatible with CryptVerifyTimeStampSignature().

To generate and upload the request in Windows, I use the CryptRetrieveTimeStamp():

```
            CRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT*re;
            CRYPT_TIMESTAMP_PARA r = { 0 };
            r.fRequestCerts = true;

            auto C = ... // my data
            auto flg = TIMESTAMP_VERIFY_CONTEXT_SIGNATURE;
            CryptRetrieveTimeStamp(url, flg, 0,
                szOID_NIST_sha256, &r, (BYTE*)C.data(), C.size(), &re, 0, 0);
```

In order to do that in php, I use openssl and curl

```
openssl ts -query -data inputfile -sha256 -cert -out file.tsq

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tsa_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($requestfile_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/timestamp-query'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
$binary_response_string = curl_exec($ch);
```

So far, good. I get a valid tsa response.
The problem is now that, while openssl can verify both responses (from Windows API and from php):

```
openssl ts -verify -sha256 -digest "..." -in r:\1.dat -CAfile file.pem
```

Windows API call fails when the response is the openssl's:

```
            PCRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT re = 0;
            BYTE* b = (BYTE*)...
            auto sz = ...
            auto Sig = ...
            auto res = CryptVerifyTimeStampSignature(b,sz, (BYTE*)Sig.data(), Sig.size(), 0, &re, p, 0);
```

Result:
        @ERR,hr 0x8009310b : ASN1 bad tag value met.    unsigned int

What could be wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `auto flg = TIMESTAMP_VERIFY_CONTEXT_SIGNATURE` - Unrelated to your issue, but seriously, why? Why use `auto`? Is saving 1 character worth introducing a subtle bug? The [type of `TIMESTAMP_VERIFY_CONTEXT_SIGNATURE` is `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). The flag argument is a `DWORD` (unsigned). You should not ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: The code demonstrated here is just for explaining the situation, and is not necessarily part of the full code. When someone discusses advanced topics like this one, it is safe to assume that they have gone through the process of understanding compiler warnings (not to say that there is not a warning because there is no comparison). Making such trivial remarks to such a question only indicates lack of knowledge to say anything valuable.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? I am seeing the same return code when passing a byte buffer containing a signature into this call

Comment: No, there is no way to use S/MIME with timestamp in Linux.

Comment: Okay no worries, thanks